# Carbon with Laravellocalization not using correct locale

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, php-carbon, laravel-localization

I am using [mcamara/laravel-localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization)
 on my project, and I'm having an issue with Carbon not recognizing locale. When I use

```
$event->start_time->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y')
```

it always displays English format, even though I get 'de' when I try

```
App::getLocale()
```

Obviously this is because carbon uses locale from operating system, and my OS has 'de_DE.utf8', so unless I do

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE.utf8')
```

it doesn't work. I obviously can't use that this way because I use multiple languages.

- **Option 1 (the bad and easy, but works):**

Define the following in routes.php (or somewhere else)

```
if(App::getLocale()=="de")
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE.utf8');
else if(App::getLocale()=="hr")
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'hr_HR.utf8');
else 
    setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en_EN.utf8');
```

- **Option 2 (the long and possibly better solution? Feels the correct one)**

Since I have this defined in routes.php

```
'prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),
```

I could extend `setLocale()` to set `LC_TIME` to the `de_DE` or anything else. But to do that I would need to extend add 'regional' to config/laravellocalization.php from

```
'de' => ['name' => 'German','script' => 'Latn', 'native' => 'Deutsch'],
```

to

```
'de' => ['regional' => 'de_DE.utf8', 'name' => 'German','script' => 'Latn', 'native' => 'Deutsch'],
```

I would also need to create a method such as this in LaravelLocalization.php (obviously I would extend the class)

```
public function getCurrentLocaleRegional()
{
    return $this->supportedLocales[ $this->getCurrentLocale() ][ 'regional' ];
}
```

Now I would like to know, which way is better? Or, is there another (easier) solution to this problem?

*I'm working on Ubuntu 15.10 in case if that matters*

**---------EDIT---------**

For anyone reading this, option 2 has been [implemented](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization/commit/9ba42945d0a3e75786a736aecb7c43f06bc94124) and released as version 1.0.12

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a key in the lang files to tell Carbon how to write the format.

Something like:

    `$event->start_time->formatLocalized(trans('general.date_format'))`

Comment: But this solution would change between 25.11.2015 and 11/25/2015, but not month or day name. But still a good solution for that, thanks